# Fresh Ubuntu 22.04.02 LTS boots without icons, panel, just a wallpaper

Tags: desktop-environments, desktop-icons

I have a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 install and everytime I boot my PC it boots without icons, without left and top panel, just the default wallpaper. I did not install any packages. It's a completely fresh install. Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Comment: Could you open a terminal (Ctrl+alt+F2) and post the output of ìnxi -G`. Check if there is a `.xsession-errors`file in your home directory, else check the journal logs.

Comment: When I press Ctrl+Alt+F2 nothing happens. I pressed Ctrl+Alt+F3 and a terminal opened but I got `zsh command not found` error.

Comment: zsh is not the default shell of ubuntu. Try to download ubuntu from a trusted site (like ubuntu).

Comment: @kanehekili what does it have to do with `inxi` command? And just for your reference, I  did download Ubuntu from the official website.